# Dynamic allocation of string in shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory, realloc

I have 2 programs (writer-reader style) and a shared memory struct established between them + of course the needed semaphores. Struct is:

```
struct shared_stuff{
    int action;
    char* text;
};
```

What I want to do is read input from user and then dynamically allocate the text string and read it from the reader end. My writer code narrowed down to the important stuff (*ss* is a pointer to the shared memory segment cast as a *struct shared_stuff**) is this:

```
ss->text=NULL;
while(1){
    printf("Waiting for user input:\n");
    char input[200];
    fgets(input,200,stdin); //i ignore the '\0' with a loop
    sem_wait(empty);
    ss->action=x;
    ss->text=(char*)realloc(ss->text,sizeof(ss->text)*strlen(input));
    strcpy(ss->text,input);
    sem_post(full);
}
```

The reader:

```
while(1){
    sem_wait(full);

    struct shared_stuff *ss;
    ss=(struct shared_stuff*) shared_memory;
        
    printf("Found action:%d\n",ss->action);
    printf("And text:%s\n",ss->text);

    sem_post(empty);
}
```

The **printf("And text...** is never even printed. It is faulty code. When I use the SAME code in the main though it prints the text perfectly.

Comment: You can't pass pointers from one process another. That is, the pointer from `realloc` in one process is not valid in the other process. You need to copy the actual data into the shared memory. Or you need to do the string allocation from shared memory as well.

Comment: I thought i was copying the data into the shared memory with the strcpy. How can I actually do it?

Comment: The easiest way is to change `char* text;` to `char text[200];` in the shared memory, I know you said you want to make that dynamic. But why? It arguably adds more complication than it is worth.

Comment: My teacher has a similar program using a char text[2048] . I just thought it would be wiser to actually allocate the needed space only. If it is that complex i might just change it

Comment: Now you know why your teacher did it that way :-)